# SpreadSheet.removeMenu removes only items under the menu and not the menu itself

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Tried the sample code under [`Spreadsheet.removeMenu()` official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removemenuname)

And it removes the menu items(`"remove bad menu"` and `"foo"`) and not the `menu(badMenu)` itself.

Isn't it supposed to remove the menu?
If not, How to I delete it?

Comment: Please post corresponding code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The menu will get removed once you refresh the Spreadsheet. But since you are using onOpen Trigger (Which run the function automatically every time the Spreadsheet is loaded) it will be added again.

Try renaming `onOpen()` function and run it manually to add the menu. Then click the sub menu `removeBadMenu`. At first it will remove the sub menu but when you refresh the Spreadsheet, the menu will get deleted.

### Reference:

- [onOpen()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene)

Comment: Tried renaming and it worked. How can I trigger a Refresh programmatically?

Comment: @Ekalavya - Unfortunately, Apps Script does not have any module that can reload a page. Having menu with empty sub-menu/content is fine since user cannot execute anything out of it.

Comment: But, this used to work.  Spreadsheet.removeMenu() did remove the entire menu. May be this is broken now?

Comment: @Ekalavya - Yes, It seems that there is a issue on removeMenu(), but there is ongoing [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202989059) discussion for that matter. I would suggest you star the post to add vote and get notified when there is an update on the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.